# How to change text color on the current tab in ActionBar xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, tabs, android-actionbar

I am new in Xamarin, and I try to change the color on my selected tab in a ActionBar like this ?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjOr5.png)

Just the text color and underline but not the background?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the design support library add this code to your tabactivity

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#727272"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'll try soon